# iOS: How to add scroll screen for 4s

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I wrote the app with size classes and constraints which looks well on iPhone from 5 to 6 Plus. But my screen doesn't fit for 4s. I thought that there is should be some kind of auto option which makes screen scrollable if it doesn't fit. But I cannot find any info about it. How I should solve my problem?

Comment: in IOS there is no such option. you need to work with UIScrollView

Comment: There is not solution other then embedding all your views in scrollviews.

Answer (score 0):

You get the scrollable feature by having a UIScrollView that contains all your other views.
[image: scrollview]

But it will become scrollable for all iPhone sizes, unless you programmatically disable `isScrollable` for some screen sizes.

Detection of screen size can be achieved with:

```
extension UIScreen {
    class var isIphone4Size: Bool {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height <= 480
    }
}
```